# Build Play2.0 documentation from source so that it is available from @documentation route locally

Tags: playframework-2.0

I installed the master version using instructions available at [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/BuildingFromSource).

However, when I try to run http://localhost:9000/@documentation the URL does not serve any content.

I assume, I need to build documentation, just like the repository had to be built, however, I have not been able to find any instructions.

This is not a problem if we install a binary/stable version. Only if building from source.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call

```
git clone git://github.com/playframework/Play20.wiki.git .
```

in `Play20/documentation/manual`
to get the api-docs you must call `build doc`. The doc-command doesn't work under windows at the moment.

[Update since 26.10.2012 there is no need for an extra pull. The documentation is now part of the main-repository. Hopefully the doc-command runs under windows now. I didn't checked it.]

Comment: Thanks. That would probably explain why doc does not work, since I was in windows. I'll try to clone the wiki today.

Comment: A quick question. Do I install it in the Play20 directory? By default it comes in Play20.wiki. It contains non-text files. Additionally it is not a play project either. Must I copy them in Play20 and run another command?

Comment: You must put it directly to `Play20/documentation/manual` this was the reason why there is a DOT at the end of the clone command.

Comment: This is not valid any more -- the documentation is now inline.  See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/Pjx8t6LGka4/Pgox658rYncJ

Comment: I have fixed it in the answer.